# scheme- why the memory terminated?

Tags: loops, scheme

There is 3 programs that I'm trying to understand  what is going on in the stack and in the heap. 
all are infinite loops

1.

```
  (let ((f (lambda () 'ok))
        (g (lambda (a b) (a a b))))
           (g g f))
```

all the application are tail recursion-the stack is ok.
 only 2 lambdas are created -so the heap is ok.
Am I right?

2.

```
   (let ((f (lambda (a b)
               (a a (lambda () 'ok)))))
     (f f (lambda () 'ok)))
```

all the applications are tail recursion-the stack is ok.
about the heap: there is infinite lambda (lambda () 'ok)) created.
Am I right?
 -so why is the memory not terminated?

And the last:

3.

```
   (let ((f (lambda (a b)
                (a a (lambda () (b))))))
       (f f (lambda () 'ok)))
```

What is the difference between 2 and 3? why in 2 the memory terminated?
If I underdatnd right, in 3 after one loop :

```
 we activate this: (lambda (a b)  (a a (lambda () (b)))
 on                (lambda (a b)  (a a (lambda () (b)))
 and this          (lambda () 'ok)  (becuse this is (b)..)
```

and this is the same as 2!

Answer (score 0):

In a smart compiler, case 1 and case 2 are equivalent. Even without a smart compiler, so that the lambdas are created afresh each time, case 2 may create an infinite number of lambdas, but they are instantly garbage-collectable. So the result is the same: constant stack and heap usage.

In case 3, each new lambda contains a free reference to the previous lambda, so none of the lambdas being created are garbage-collectable. You still have constant stack usage, but the heap usage will balloon. (A really smart compiler can figure out that the lambda is actually unused, and eliminate that entirely, but my general point about free references holds.)

A compiler can also replace `(lambda () (b))` with `b` directly if it can prove that `b` is already a nullary(-only) procedure, and/or if it can prove that the resultant lambda will only be called in a nullary fashion (otherwise, it has to add type and arity checkers). Again, for that to apply to your example, it would take a pretty smart compiler.

Comment: thanks! Can you expalin why "each new lambda contains a free reference to the previous lambda"?

Comment: `(lambda () (b))` contains a free reference to `b`, which is the previous lambda. So the latter cannot be collected as long as this new lambda holds a reference to it.